# Pronunciation of daneben

Tags: pronunciation

I have checked Leo, Duden and some other online dictionaries but can not get a clear answer. I am curious how you as native speaking Germans would pronounce the word:

> daneben

According to Wiktionary the pronunciation is: [ˈdaːneːbm̩]. Can this word be pronounced: [ˈdaːneːb**n**]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In careful speech, it's [daˈneːbən], but the usual pronunciation is
[daˈneːbm̩]:
The schwa after /b/ is dropped, so the final /n/ becomes syllabic, moreover /n/ is assimilated to /b/, so it is turned into a syllabic /m/.

Note: In most contexts, I would *not* stress the first syllable, and if /a/ is not stressed, I would *not* pronounce it as a long vowel.

Comment: regionally that final bn might even morph into a wn-sound

Answer (score -2):

*DUH - nae - Bin*, whereas the DUH and B are stressed, and the *i* is as short as possible — you really want it to sound like *Bin* or *Bun* but extremely short vowels, it’s just — *Bn*.

you could also just say *-naeBn* as one syllable, drawing it together a bit, speaking it faster, but it can be tricky and you have to try what you like better.

There is an *n* at the end of the word and you hear it, but it’s a bit softer because of the strong *B* sound before. In German, that super short vowel in there is an *e* from *daneb**e**n*, which in that case is spoken as a very short *öh* or *uh* — it just not there.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your ‘pronunciation syllabics’. Why don’t you use IPA?